# How do I filter a Spark dataframe by date?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

So, the spark dataframe I am using has a field "a" which contains timestamp data, but due to issues in writing the data, has "string" field.

I want to execute a certain sql on the dataframe that involves "AND" and "OR" logic as follows:

```
select * from df where ((df.a>="2018-09-01" AND df.b==1) OR
(df.a>="2019-12-31" AND df.b==2))
```

So, I tried this snippet for the first part:

```
val new_df=df.filter((df("b")==1 && 
to_date(df("a")) >= to_date(lit("2018-09-01"))))
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
<console>:25: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Column
 required: Boolean
       val new_df=df.filter((df("b")==1 && to_date(df("start_date")) >= to_date(lit("2018-09-01"))))
```

How should I do this for the entire logic I want?

Comment: just wrap the date in `lit`

Comment: Thanks. Could you please help with the edited version?

Comment: use triple equals `===`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lit` function.

```
val new_df=df.filter(to_date(df("a")) >= to_date(lit("2018-09-01")))
```

```
val new_df=df.filter((df("b")=== lit(1) && 
to_date(df("a")) >= to_date(lit("2018-09-01"))))
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please help with the edited version?